# How can I cross compile my rust when it needs to use a separate windows API?

Tags: linux, windows, rust, cross-compiling, lib

I've been programming in rust and i've been making a packet sniffing program that operates on layer 2 however the confines of the OS I'm programming on (Chrome OS) have compelled me to cross-compile my application to Windows.

I have added Windows as a target on cargo and got mingw-w64 as my linker as directed by a separate post on this same [website](https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet) however I ended up receiving this error after this leading to my final obstacle "cannot find -lPacket"

My final goal is to download WinPcap or npcap on linux just for the purpose of using the library in building my project but I don't know how to do so, [I know I must do it because of what the requirements on the site for the package I'm using specified](https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet)

My question is how do I download either of those libraries and access them on Linux to compile my program to Windows, I don't have any idea how I am to achieve my goals?